# Vue js input mask

Tags: vue.js

I want to have an input mask on a specific input where it parses the user input into a human readable US phone number.

For example

User enter: 1231231234
User sees: (123)-123-1234

What I have done so far is, i made a watch method like the follow

```
switch (this.form.values.primary_phone.length) {
        case 3:
          return this.form.values.primary_phone = this.form.values.primary_phone.replace(/^([0-9]{3})$/, '($1)');
        case 6:
          return this.form.values.primary_phone = this.form.values.primary_phone.replace(/^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})$/, '($1)-$2');
        case 10:
          return this.form.values.primary_phone = this.form.values.primary_phone.replace(/^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})$/, '($1)-$2-$3');
      }
```

Now this updates the value only when I focus out of from input. Is there a way I can do it to update while the input is still at focus?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to do a directive wrapping the [jquery plugin input mask](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#inputmask-examples).

There is an example:

**JavaScript**

```
Vue.directive('input-mask', {
  params: ['mask'],

  bind: function() {
    $(this.el).inputmask({
      mask: this.params.mask
    });

  },
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    value: '',
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Import Styles/Scripts from the plugin and do not forget the jQuery library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<p>Selected: {{value}}</p>
<input v-model="value" v-input-mask mask="(999) 999-9999">
```

If you need there is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/dozice/edit?html,js,output) to show you how it works.

Comment: I would not recommend using jQuery to solve this, rather I would use Vue's built-in `filter` method, or a combination of `v-bind:value` and `v-on:keyDown`, similar to what's shown here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events

Answer (score 3):

For that you must define a [custom filter](http://vuejs.org/guide/custom-filter.html) on your input. Something like this

```js
Vue.filter('mask', function (value) {
  if (value.length <= 3){
    var re = new RegExp("^([0-9]{"+value.length+"})$");
    return value = value.replace(re, '($1)');
  } 
  if (value.length > 3 && value.length <= 6){
    var re = new RegExp("^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{"+ (value.length - 3)+"})$");
    return value = value.replace(re, '($1)-$2');
  }
  if (value.length > 6 && value.length <= 10){
    var re = new RegExp("^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{"+(value.length-6)+"})$");
    return value = value.replace(re, '($1)-$2-$3');
  }
    return value;
})
```

Then apply that to your template. I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/904f45tj/1/) (based on the [markdown example](http://vuejs.org/examples/index.html) from Vue page)

Notice that you still have to handle values of length greater than 10, and I also changed your function to use `if` statements instead of `switch-case`

Answer (score 0):

I use the text-mask plugin which give the same great functionality as the JQuery one without the Jquery bloat.

Github here: https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask

Vue instructions here: https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/vue

```js
const MaskedInput = window.vueTextMask.default
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { MaskedInput },
    data: {
        phone: '',
        mask: ['(', /\d/, /\d/,/\d/, ')', '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-text-mask@6.1.2/dist/vueTextMask.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    phone:
    <masked-input v-model="phone" :mask="mask" placeholder="(___)-___-____"></masked-input>
</div>
```